# URL redirect on updating the post date

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess

I updated the date in the post. But the old URL has already gone viral and people end up in a deadlink as "page not found". I tried using Simple 301 Redirect WordPress Plugin and also Permalink Redirect WordPress Plugin. But it does not seem to work.

I want to redirect from `http://www.example.com/2014/02/20/events-2014/` to `http://www.example.com/2014/03/02/events-2014/`

Also all my Mobile apps are synced to the website. I do not want them to get affected because of this redirection.

Comment: how about changing the date back? The date should reflect the time the post was published..... Anyway I find it hard to believe that the plugins don't work (simple 301 redirect is truly very simple and basic) what exactly happens?

Answer (score 0):

You could try redirecting without a plugin, using the .htaccess file.

This file can be found at wordpress root folder, if all you want to do is redirect this specific page, you could open and insert the following line (at the first line of the .htaccess)

Redirect 301 /2014/02/20/events-2014/ http://www.example.com/2014/03/02/events-2014/

Comment: The problem right now is.. I do not have permission to write in .htaccess file.